# Why returned FILE* retains data when command in popen() fails

Tags: c++, linux, pipe, popen, glibc

I am working on a program which uses popen() to find a file. Then copies the data in stream returned by popen() into a char array and prints it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

int main()
{
        char command[1024];
        char ch = 'a';
        FILE* pf;
        while(ch < 'd')
        {
                sprintf(command, "find /home/ypatil/interest -name \\%c.out", ch);
                std::cout << std::endl << command << std::endl;
                pf = popen(command, "r");
                if(pf)
                {
                        char src[256];
                        fgets(src, 256, pf);
                        std::cout << std::endl << "pf = " << src << std::endl;  
                }
                pclose(pf);
                ++ch;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Now, I am doing this in loop and I found out that if file program is searching doesn't exist, then file stream `pf` retains its old value. Only `a.out` file exists on my system. So, the output of this program is -

```
find /home/ypatil/interest -name \a.out

pf = /home/ypatil/interest/a.out


find /home/ypatil/interest -name \b.out

pf = /home/ypatil/interest/a.out

find /home/ypatil/interest -name \c.out

pf = /home/ypatil/interest/a.out
```

So, you can see that `find` is searching for different files and only `a.out` exists.  So, it will fail for other files. But, still `pf` retains its data in every iteration. I want to know why it retains value of `FILE *` returned by `popen` in previous iterataion.
Thank you.

Comment: You ask `popen` to execute the `find` program, which it does. If the `find` program fails or not is irrelevant as the `popen` *still executes it*.

Comment: There are things *you* fail to do on the other hand. For example you call `fflush(pf)` *unconditionally* even if `popen` fails and returns a null pointer. And you call `fgets` *without checking if it succeeds!*

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - My question is why FILE* pf data remains same even if find fails? When find command fails to find given file, it returns nothing on stdout. 
The whole point to use fgets() is that to prove FILE* pf is pointing to previous data in next iteration. Shouldn't pf have new value?

Comment: You have exactly zero evidence that `pf` doesn't have a new value, and exactly zero reason to believe that it *should* have a new value, or NULL. All you have here is a series of elementary programming bugs that prove exactly nothing,

Comment: That's not how `popen` and `FILE` pointers work. The `popen` function will only return a null pointer (that you should not pass to `fflush`!) if it fails to actually *execute* the program. The program executes, but gives no output which is checked by [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) returning a null pointer!

Comment: Yiur claim can be separated in two parts. One, that fgets successfully reads a fresh line from a file; and two, that said line is mysteriously the same as a line previously read from a totally different file. Now do you understand that if the first claim turns out to be untrue, there is no fresh line to be compared to some other line? Can you verify or falsify the first claim?

Answer (score 1):

> Shoudn't it be NULL when `find` fails?

No, it should be a valid `FILE *` embodying the piped output of the `find` process. If the process doesn't produce any output, reading it will produce an immediate EOF. Starting the `find` process isn't failing here: it is just not finding anything.

Unclear why you think otherwise.

Comment: So, when find process fails, it doesn't sends any output. So, shouldn't FILE * pf be pointing to EOF, instead of holding to the old data in out stream?

Comment: 'Pointing to EOF' is meaningless, and 'pointing to' anything is not the same thing as being NULL-valued. A `FILE *` points to an object of type `FILE`, and reading via that should *produce* an immediate EOF if it's empty. I've already said all that. And as you aren't *checking* for EOF you don't have any reason to believe it isn't being produced.